# Уведомление об ошибке в web-приложении

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос такой: у меня есть готовое web-приложение, неизвестно, как и на чем написанное, переписывать его полностью на нормальный php и js нет ни сил, ни времени, ни желания. Нужно сделать приложение, которое будет информировать меня о том, что в работе приложения ошибка: либо потеря связи с сервером, либо потеря связи с базой данных. Необходимо это для того, чтобы не заходить каждый раз на сервер и не проверять работоспособность приложения у другого пользователя.

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать.

Comment: @annet1806, а как именно вы определяете, что в работе приложения произошла та или иная ошибка? Приложение выдаёт эту ошибку на экран при открытии стрвницы? Или, может, пишет что-то в лог?

Comment: 1. успокоиться
2. переписать текст вопроса красиво
3. добавить отступы и абзацы
4. разобраться, на чем все таки написано приложение
5. если это не реально - выложить код
6. определиться, что такое "в работе приложения ошибка"
7. понять, что php - это не всегда "нормальный".
8. позвать телепатов
9. начать радоваться жизни.

Comment: При открытии приложения в браузере ошибка выводится на экран с временным определением, например потеря соединения с сервером произошло 3 минуты назад

Comment: Я бы с радостью успокоилась, но уже терпения и зла на это приложение не хватает, а начальство требует прямо сейчас в сию же секунду, чтобы шефу либо на телефон приходило сообщение о том, что это безобразие опять соединение потеряло, либо какое-то стороннее приложение, установленное у него на ноут, кричало громко и противно об этом, что самое интересное, приложение написано на php, но написано оно коряво, и половина того, что должно там работать, не работает, а сейчас просто катастрофически нет времени сидеть и полностью переписывать код, боюсь, что телепаты в данном случае мне не помогут)

Comment: Ну, придет начальству на телефон сообщение? и что, он сам пойдет  исправлять? 

В любом случае делайте watchdog - такую отдельную программу, которая раз в минуту(в час, в день) делает нужные запросы-проверки - подключается к базе, дергает известную страницу и проверяет ее содержимое, замеряет время ответа. Для написания подобного сильно знать устройство сайта/программы не нужно знать. 

К такому вачдогу хорошо прикрутить перезапуск сервисов/составляющих частей.

Answer (score 1):

[monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) решает описанную задачу. См. [примеры конфигураций](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#configuration_examples), чтобы понять что к чему.

+ сервис для отправки смс, [например](http://sms.ru).